# How to annotate unknown in advance libraries in TypeScript types definitions?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

In below type definitions for [gulp-postcss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-postcss) on `parser?: Object;` play any npm-library could be. How I should to annotate it?

```js
/// <reference types="node"/>
import Vinyl = require('vinyl');

declare function GulpPostCss(plugins?: string[], options?: GulpPostCss.Options): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream;
declare function GulpPostCss(callback?: (file: Vinyl) => { plugins?: string[], options?: GulpPostCss.Options }):
    NodeJS.ReadWriteStream;

declare namespace GulpPostCss {
    interface Options {
        parser?: Object;
    }
}

export = GulpPostCss;
```

Off course `any` or `Object` is the last solution, when no other solutions exists (by the way [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) do not accepts `Object` type).

Comment: Do you have to support TypeScript 2.x? If not, does the [unknown](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) type serve your needs?

Comment: @Cerberus, sorry for late answer. I think, I don't need to support TypeScript 2.x. I see, I suppose it's better than `any`.

Comment: I see. I'll add this as an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Typescript 3.0, there is a new language item called [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type). It is somewhat analogous to `any`, meaning that it could hold every value possible (everything is assignable to `unknown`), but with one large difference: with `any` you can do anything straight away, but with `unknown` you *can't* do anything or assign it to anything without checking first what value have you really got (or using an explicit [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html), if you're sure what you've got). It is the most adequate variant to choose when there is some arbitrary mapping.

If you have to support pre-3.0 versions, you can emulate `unknown` type by making a union, as it's done [here](https://github.com/gcanti/unknown-ts):

```js
export type mixed = { [key: string]: any } | object | number | string | boolean | symbol | undefined | null | void;

declare global {
  type unknown = mixed;
}
```

This has a downside, however, that you can't easily include indexed types - note that the values in `{ [key: string]: any }` there are `any`, not `unknown`, since the latter would make definition directly recursive.

---

Side note about `Object` type: I don't know any use case where it can't be safely replaced by `object`, except explicitly typing the constructors. That seems to be the reason it is not accepted by DefinitelyTyped. One caveat is that `object` type is somewhat more limiting, since you can't store, for example, a `string` in it (but can store the `String` object).